# RSS via Ubuntu Apache PHP - content delivered but not recognized by reader

Tags: php, rss, header, ubuntu-8.04

This is a little difficult to explain so please bear with me :

Using FF as my RSS reader to test,

I am migrating a site which has an RSS Feed component to it;  on the old server (apache on fedora 7) the PHP delivers the RSS, and the content is parsed and displayed in the browser.

In the new site, (apache on Ubuntu 8.04) the browser recognizes that it is a feed, but it displays no data.  But when you view source, the code is visible in the source viewer.

the code is simple:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo getRss();
```

By means of testing, I copy/pasted the code from the view-source window into a text file, and served it via straight .xml from the ubuntu server.  It parses just fine.

So it seems that the problem is delivering the XML via PHP over ubuntu 8.04

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by turning on mod_deflate.

a2enmod deflate
/etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload

The data was coming in chunked, but the request only allowed gzip/deflate